How to reduce the height of the graph itself react-native-chart-kit kit yt
i cant understand the reason behind this problem
tried searching it on internet but wasnt able to get a suitable answer
help me with this as it is very important for me as a student to clear this doubt
hoping for clear and easy solution with the main problem
